# How to iterate through an object returned by fetchAll?

Tags: database

Since fetchAssoc was returning only one row, i was forced to use fetchAll.

The problem is fetchAll returns the data as an array of objects. Iterating through them is kind of painful, not impossible but seems like a long way to go for something that should be really simple.

fetchAllAssoc throws an error.

If somebody could show me a neater trick, that would be great.

```
    $result = db_select('raffles', 'r')
  ->fields('r')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAll();

  dpm($result);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
// Retrieve all records into an indexed array of stdClass objects.
$info = $result->fetchAll();

// Retrieve all records into an associative array
// keyed by the field in the result specified.
$info = $result->fetchAllAssoc($field)
```

To iterate just use:

```
foreach($info as $key => $object) {
  print $object->property . "<br>";
}
```

**References:**

https://www.drupal.org/node/1251174